# Split Screen layout in Angular Material fullscreen issue

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to create a split screen layout in Angular Material but my elements are not going full screen.

```
 <md-content layout="column">

<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" flex>
<div layout="column" flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50"  style="background-color: red;">

    <!-- left split screen -->
    <div flex="100" layout="column">
    <h1>hello</h1>

    </div>
</div> 

<!-- right split screen -->
<div layout="column" flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50"  style="background-color: blue;">
    <div flex="100" layout="column">
        <h1>angular</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's my plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9nA97Z83zgMcAeti7wh3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the body layout to **row**, so it takes the full height, the **add flex to the md-content** component and voila! you have the full screen you want.

```
<body ng-app="YourApp" layout="row">
  <md-content ng-controller="TestCtrl" layout="column" flex>
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <div layout="column" flex="50"  style="background-color: red;">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
      <div layout="column" flex="50"  style="background-color: #bada55;">
        <h1>angular</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3crCJLGrpUNUUGqf1aqb?p=preview).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to added into your css

```
.layout-row{
  height:100vh; 
}
```

here is the planker with full screen [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oDm5Svo5H2mGYMA5wuuu?p=preview)